# Websocket connection keeps failing when trying to deploy a dockerized PERN stack webapp to digital ocean droplet

Tags: socket.io, nestjs, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm struggling with that for 5 days now and I can't get myself out of this.

Here is some context: I coded a web application for chatting, playing, adding friends .. with:

Note: For my web sockets gateways , I created a gateway on port 4002 for Chat, a gateway on port 4006 for friendship interface, and a gateway on port 4010 for the game.

Here is an example of how I initiate the connection with sockets (for instance: friendship interface)

**Client side**:

```js
const socket = io("http://localhost:4006")
```

**Backend side**:

```js
@WebSocketGateway(4006, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000'], // this is the url client side
        credentials: true,
    },
})
```

I dockerized the whole application and serve my React application with nginx webserver. When I launch it locally with "docker compose up --build" everything is working perfectly and I've got my websockets connections working fine.

When I decided to deploy this docker app to Digital ocean droplet, I added nginx as reverse proxy and SSL, I chose a 4GB droplet, and I bought a domain name as: pimpmypong.live that I linked to my droplet.

Here is my nginx configuration file:

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:4001 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream frontend {
    server localhost:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /socket3/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4006;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

... ssl configuration
```

Here is how I changed my code to fit this:

**Client side**:

```js
const socket = io("https://pimpmypong.live/socket3")
```

**Backend side**:

```js
@WebSocketGateway(4006, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['https://pimpmypong.live]})

This configuration still doesn't work and i am still getting "Websocket connection failed" 
Can someone help with this, i really tried every possible solution but without result
```